# Carriage Return & Line Feed acts as Char values

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox

I've got a HEX to RGB converter program that accepts string inputs from two fields: A Textbox for RGB and a Textbox for HEX. Each box searches for a specific string length from specific values.

For example, if the user enters a string of 7 characters "#0000FF", only the 6 values representing RGB are processed. I.E. the '#' is Replaced with "".

Recently I've been finding that inputting only 4 valid characters, such as "000F" will result in crash. I've put a break point at the if-statement related to the .Length of the string, and it seems that 2 characters are added to the value.

So after typing "0", the length is now 3 and the input is equivalent to "0\r\n". After Typing "00", the length is then 4 and the input equivalent is "00\r\n" - and so forth.

Is there a simple way to remove the "\r" and "\n" values of the string? Why is it that Carriage Return and Line Feed appear in the textbox inputs at all?

Comment: AcceptsReturn = false?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 both textboxes are set to false.

Comment: Just remove it with a `String.replace`.

Comment: @zx485 That's a valid solution - I assumed it would be more difficult. If you know the answer to the conceptual question, I will mark your response as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be using `String.Replace` to remove the `\r` and `\n` chars from the String:

```
String test = textbox1.Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","");
```

This removes all CR and LF characters from the `TextBox`es string.

Comment: Do you know why the CR and LF chars appear in the first place?

Comment: Because in Windows pressing the 'Enter'/'Return' key does generate these two chars(0Dh,0Ah) in the keyboard buffer. It's a convention. In Linux it's just 0Ah=LF.